# bluetooth printing in android

Tags: android

i am developing a android application in which i need to print the string data  using bluetooth.

Can anyone help me out with the problem.

I am using Google nexus and Samsung Galaxy Tab,

Answer (score 2):

you have to used bluetooth apis for that like bluetooth adapter for searching a device and bluetooth sockets for connecting bluetooth devices.you also need to set some permission in manifest file for using bluetooth apis,this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) will help you..